# Oracle insert select max + 1 into same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I thought this would be easy, but i am not able to get my head around this. I want to avoid pl/sql, preferably want this done in plain sql. So in the below sql i am trying to insert into agreement_tbl, by selecting from another table employee_agreement. The employee agreement table returns about 6000 rows. So for each row insert what i want is unique max(agreement_nbr) + 1 inserted in the AGREEMENT_NBR column.

The problem is, since the sql executes first, the max(agreement_nbr) is always the same say 5000, and when i try to insert max(agreement_nbr) it throws 'Unique constraint exception' as it tries to insert value 5000 for all the 6000 inserts. How do i get the unique max+1 for each row from the select query? This is probably like inserting and selection from the same table. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Edit: This is a one time script, and the agreement_tbl is already populated with thousands of records.

```
INSERT
INTO
    Agreement_tbl
    (
        AGREEMENT_NBR,
        Employee_id,
        AGREEMENT_TEXT
    )   
      select            
         (select max(AGREEMENT_NBR)+1 from Agreement_tbl) as AGREEMENT_NBR,
          a.Employee_id ,
         a.AGREEMENT_TEXT
     from  employee_agreement
      -- some where conditions
```

Comment: Why not use a sequence?

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE`.  Your `max(AGREEMENT_NBR)+1` solution won't work for more than one user at a time, besides being slower and more complicated.

Comment: A sequence is a much better, and more reliable way for you to do this. That will maintain the current sequence for your table for any future inserts. Aside from that, if you want to continue your original approach... Is `Agreement_tbl` currently empty, and you are trying to populate it using this method? If this is a one time DML to populate this table then this might be the one time a sequence may add no value to the solution.

Comment: @gmiley  Yes, the table is already populated with 1000's of records, and this is a one time script. Since this is just a one time thing, i thought sequence will not provide much value.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak this is a one time script, and no other user will write at this time.

Comment: @PaulAbbott thanks, thought about it but Since this is just a one time thing, i thought sequence will not provide much value ?

Comment: Beware that a one-time script is only a one-time script until the bosses find out it worked. Then it is no longer one-time. (Trust me on this!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `rownum` instead of `+1`. 
Rownum is 1 for the first row , 2 for the second etc.:

```
INSERT
INTO
    Agreement_tbl
.......
      select            
         rownum + (select max(AGREEMENT_NBR) from Agreement_tbl) as AGREEMENT_NBR,
          a.Employee_id ,
         a.AGREEMENT_TEXT
     from  employee_agreement
      -- some where conditions
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought i tried this, but my bad i had the + rownum inside the max subquery which made it not work. It works now, thanks